# How to apply eventListener to all input className

Tags: javascript, events

I want to add EventListener to all input className that will **disable space** when typing using oninput.

```
input class="inputX" id="idA"></input>
input class="inputX" id="idB"></input>
input class="inputX" id="idC"></input>
input class="inputX" id="idD"></input>
```

Im using FOR statement and still nowhere.
It can be done if im using getElementById but not with getElementsByClassName/Name and even with querySelectorAll (which I believe there is some code missing).

I found JQuery code but I dont know how to write it back in Javascript.

```
$(".inputX").keyup(function() {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ""));
```

Hope someone can help me out ~ Thanks

Manage to disable space when using getElementById (as below), but how to use getElementsByClassName?

```js
document.getElementById("idA").addEventListener("input", myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("idA");
  x.value = x.value.replace(/\s/g, "");
}
```

```html
<input class="inputX" id="idA"></input><br />
<input class="inputX" id="idB"></input><br />
<input class="inputX" id="idC"></input><br />
<input class="inputX" id="idD"></input><br />
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName and querySelectorAll should work fine … but we can't see why your attempt isn't working if you don't provide a [mcve]

Comment: my attempt to disable space on all the input fields by targeting their className..mind help me out? thanks

Comment: Your edit targets IDs, not class names.

Comment: disable space working with target ID. But when change to className space can be use.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to understand the difference between `getElementsByClassName` and `querySelectorAll`. First one creates **HTMLCollection[]** while latter one creates a **NodeList[]**.

**HTMLCollection[]** cannot be iterated with `forEach` while **NodeList[]** can:

```js
const withClassName = document.getElementsByClassName('foo');
const withQuerySelector = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');

console.log(withClassName.forEach);
console.log(withQuerySelector.forEach);
```

```html
<div class='foo'></div>
```

Therefore I recommend using `document.querySelectorAll()` in your case with following code:

```js
const foos = document.querySelectorAll('.foo');

foos.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener('keyup', (evt) => {
    console.log(evt.currentTarget.value);
  });
});
```

```html
<input class='foo' />
<br />
<input class='foo' />
```

Comment: i think im not asking the right question xD. Im trying to applied evenListener to all input class, which disable space in each of input fields. I want all input fields cannot use space when typing.. is it possible?

Comment: Done, thanks @Samuli Hakoniemi ^^. Replaced console log with : elem.value = elem.value.replace(/\s/g, "") and its working.

Comment: @BlackHaikal yes, I left you some work to do on that so you understand it better what is actually going on :)